# Caching in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on e-commerce website in which I want to implement hole punch caching.

Right now I am implemented full page caching with redis

Problem I am facing right now is that dynamic content of the website is not able to see.

Can any one help me with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing whole page cache break down into several elements. For example in a page you may show products, providers and similar kinda details.

Store each of them in a different hash maps and have last modified time for them.

To get the whole page get each items from the cache build it on run time.

While getting each item check for the last modified time with the DB. Or whenever there is a modification update the cache.

In this way you can handle updates as well.

Hope this helps